# Why have multiple tables in SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been working with SQL queries for a fair few years. And today was the first time I came across this syntax

```
Select *    
from Table1, Table2
```

Is this the same as a full join? I have not encountered this type of joins before.. does it implicitly do the required joins from the tables?

Ta

Comment: This is the same as a `cross join`.  It is archaic syntax and should be avoided.  Use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Yes the syntax is over 25 years old now. The WHERE clause should define the join condition if it's an Inner.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question

"Select *
from Table1, Table2"

does not connect the tables, it produces cartesian product

(quot. the product of two sets: the product of set X and set Y is the set that contains all ordered pairs ( x , y ) for which x belongs to X and y belongs to Y.)

should you want to join these tables, you will write the joining manually:

Select *
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where t1.key = t2.key;

there is a longer discussion over the net, about the two possible joining methods (joins vs where's), but both methods are equivalent (with a small exception). feel free to use the one you consider more user-friendly